# GWT.create vs new operator alternative

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have to use parametric constructor of my class in GWT.create, but GWT only calls default constructor. I was thinking to replace call of GWT.create with call to new Class(arguments list). Is it the right way to code in GWT deferred binding.

Code is below:

```
public interface ProductSelectorMetaFactory extends BeanFactory.MetaFactory {
        BeanFactory<ProductSelectorTile> getProductSelectorTileFactory();
    }

public CustomTileGrid(DataSource cardViewDataSource, ProductSelectorTile tileType, String fieldState,
            List<DetailViewerField> list) {
        setDataSource(cardViewDataSource);
        setAutoFetchData(true);
        GWT.create(ProductSelectorMetaFactory.class);
        setTileConstructor(tileType.getClass().getName());
    }
```

Here I want to use parameter constructor of ProductSelectorTile class. How can I use this.

Any help is appreciated.
I might be not good in explaining my current problem but feel free if you have any doubt to understand this question.

Comment: Please note that generators (in case that's what you're trying to use) are deprecated (kind of). You should use annotation processors for any new development.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper class with no parameters that can be created by `GWT.create()`. That helper class can have different implementations - the same as your original class (with parameters). Now, each implementation of helper class can create a proper instance of the original class.

Let's assume that you need different implementations for each user agent. In `<module>.gwt.xml` you would have this (see [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html)):

```
<replace-with class="<module.path>.MyClassHelperGecko">
  <when-type-is class="<module.path>.MyClassHelper" />
  <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />
</replace-with>

<replace-with class="<module.path>.MyClassHelperSafari">
  <when-type-is class="<module.path>.MyClassHelper" />
  <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="safari" />
</replace-with>

...
```

The helper class and its implementations:

```
public class MyClassHelper {
    MyClassInterface getInstance(String param) {
        return null;
    };
}

public class MyClassHelperGecko extends MyClassHelper {
    @Override
    public MyClassInterface getInstance(String param) {
        return new MyClassGecko(param);
    }
}

public class MyClassHelperSafari extends MyClassHelper {
    @Override
    public MyClassInterface getInstance(String param) {
        return new MyClassSafari(param);
    }
}

...
```

And finally implementations of the base class:

```
public interface MyClassInterface {
    // ...
}

public class MyClassGecko implements MyClassInterface {
    public MyClassGecko(String param) {
        Window.alert("Gecko implementation; param = " + param);
        // ...
    }
}

public class MyClassSafari implements MyClassInterface {
    public MyClassSafari(String param) {
        Window.alert("Safari implementation; param = " + param);
        // ...
    }
}

...
```

Use it like this and you will see different alerts for different user-agents:

```
MyClassHelper helper = GWT.create(MyClassHelper.class);
helper.getInstance("abc");
```

This is a general `Deferred Binding Using Replacement` solution. There is also `Deferred Binding using Generators` method. Once you get the idea you can choose the method that is best for you.